# CSS list padding increasing with each level

Tags: html, css

I have some css code that make list style increase left padding to 4px each level. But I'm aware that the level of increment in the future may be out of hand. So can we loop the increment of padding through each level of list like below ?

```
#menu-panel .navbar-nav > li{padding:0px;}
#menu-panel .navbar-nav > li > ul > li{padding:5px 0 5px 4px;}
#menu-panel .navbar-nav > li > ul > li > ul > li{padding:5px 0 5px 8px;}
#menu-panel .navbar-nav > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li{padding:5px 0 5px 12px;}
```

Comment: there is no need actually to increase left margin for added new ul. you can do it in single css line of code also.

Comment: Thank you, I tried and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#menu-panel .navbar-nav  li{padding-left:4px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I just needed to do that:

```
#menu-panel .navbar-nav > li{padding:0px;}
#menu-panel .navbar-nav > li ul > li{padding:5px 0 5px 8px;}
```